# Parabolic rescaling and time-shift in Theorem 6.2 of Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background

Tags: partial-differential-equations, ricci-flow

Picture below are from [Entropy and heat kernel bounds on a Ricci flow background](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.07093.pdf). I don't know how to use parabolic rescaling and time-shift to assume $r=1,t=1$.

$M$ is a manifold, and $g_t$ is Ricci flow.

$H_n$-center: A point $(z,t)\in M\times I$ is called an $H_n$-center of a point $(x_0,t_0)\in M\times I$ if $t<t_0$ and
$$
Var_t(\delta_z, \nu_{x_0,t_0~;t})\le H_n(t_0-t)
$$
where $H_n$ is a constant, and
$$
Var_t(\delta_z, \nu_{x_0,t_0;t}) =\int_M\int_M d^2(x_1,x_2) \delta_z(x_1) dg_t(x_1) d\nu_{x_0,t_0~;t}(x_2)
$$
is the variance of measures. $d\nu_{x_0,t_0~;t}$ is conjugate heat kernel measure, namely, denoting $d\nu_{x_0,t_0~;t}=K(x_0,t_0;\cdot, t) dg_t$, and $\Box^*=-\partial_t -\Delta_{g_t} +R$, then
$$
\Box_{x,t}^* K(x_0,t_0; x, t) =0,~~~\lim_{t\rightarrow t_0^-}K(x_0,t_0; x, t) =\delta_{x_0}(x)
$$

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]
> [image]